# How to manually modify history in angular.js

Tags: angularjs, url, angular-routing

I'm trying to remove querystring (with invitation token) from url without redirecting page.

So example url looks like:

`example.com/?invitation=fooo`

I have included ng-router, and I'm using hashbang (I can't use html5 mode in our project) for routes, but this query string is part of main url (before #), because I want the server to see it.

In regular app I would just use history API:

`history.replaceState(null, null, '/');`

But in application with Angular it causes an error:

`Error: [$rootScope:infdig] 10 $digest() iterations reached. Aborting!`

I can't use $location.path, because AFAIK it allows to modify only angular routable part of url i.e. the part after # in my case. $location.search don't even see it.

Do you know the way to remove querystring from url with angular without redirecting the page?

Answer (score 1):

In Angular, all modification of the URL should happen through the `$location` service. You can clear the query string by calling the [`$location.search`](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24location) method with an empty object: `$location.search({})`. Also, check out the guide on how to use the `$location` service [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/dev_guide.services.%24location)

Comment: Like I said, this query string is not in routable part, because it's before hashbang and I'm not using html5mode. $location.search don't see it :/ and can't modify it.

Comment: What's a "routable" part? `$location` is perfectly able to alter URLs like `http://www.foo.com?bar=23#baz`.

Comment: As I'm in hashbang mode, example url may look like:
`www.example.com/?invitation=fooo#!/base/path?foo=bar#baz`
by routable part I mean this after #!